# Delete all Excel columns except those named

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to adapt some code i found. I need to look in two rows not just one. 
I added this. But not sure how to finish this off to include this in the loop. Please could someone help.

```
Sub DeleteColumns()
    Dim currentColumn As Integer
    Dim columnHeading As String
    Dim columnHeading2 As String

    For currentColumn = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count To 1 Step -1
        columnHeading = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Cells(1, currentColumn).Value

    'Check whether to preserve the column
        Select Case columnHeading
        'Insert name of columns to preserve
            Case "NET EFFECTIVE", "OUTGOINGS"
                'Do nothing
            Case Else

            Select Case columnHeading2
            Case "HKD/sq.ft", "USD/sq.m."

            Case Else

                'Delete the column
                ActiveSheet.Columns(currentColumn).Delete
            End Select
        Next
    End Sub
```

Comment: Are you asking how to set `columnHeading2` to the value of the second cell in the column? If so, just replace `1` with `2` in the `columnHeading` assignment. You are also missing an `End Select`.

Answer (score 1):

Different approach on your code. This one worked for me

```
Sub DeleteColumns()
    Dim currentColumn As Integer
    Dim columnHeading As String        

    For currentColumn = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count To 1 Step -1
        columnHeading = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Cells(1, currentColumn).Value

If columnHeading = "One" Or columnHeading = "Two" Then
    GoTo label
    Else
    ActiveSheet.Columns(currentColumn).Delete
End If
label:
Next
End Sub
```

Simply replace `"One"` and `"Two"` with your desired column names. You can expand the `IF` conditions to fit your needs

Comment: Thanks for the help. Is there anyway to speed this up even more? just delete all the unwanted columns in one go?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by *speed up*? Feel free to mark this as answer if it helped you :)

Answer (score 0):

thank you lokusking!

I changed a little and it worked!!

```
Sub DeleteColumns()
    Dim currentColumn As Integer
    Dim columnHeading As String
    Dim columnHeading1 As String

    For currentColumn = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count To 1 Step -1
        columnHeading = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Cells(4, currentColumn).Value
        columnHeading1 = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Cells(5, currentColumn).Value

If columnHeading1 = "HKD/sq.ft" Or columnHeading1 = "USD/sq.m." Or columnHeading = "Outgoings" Or columnHeading = "Net effective" Then
    GoTo label
    Else
    ActiveSheet.Columns(currentColumn).Delete
End If
label:
Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

your working code could be simplified as follows:

```
Sub DeleteColumns()
    Dim currentColumn As Integer
    Dim columnHeading As String
    Dim columnHeading1 As String

    With ActiveSheet.UsedRange
        For currentColumn = .Columns.Count To 1 Step -1
            columnHeading = .Cells(4, currentColumn).Value
            columnHeading1 = .Cells(5, currentColumn).Value
            If Not (columnHeading1 = "HKD/sq.ft" Or columnHeading1 = "USD/sq.m." Or columnHeading = "Outgoings" Or columnHeading = "Net effective") Then .Columns(currentColumn).Delete
        Next currentColumn
    End With
End Sub
```